# React-Redux - Getting error "Warning : flattenChildren(...) Encountered two children with the same key

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am just getting started with React and Redux. I am following on a course on Udemy, coding the sample showin in course and pushing them to my GitHub repo so that i can peruse my progress later.

Course on Udemy : 
[Modern React with Redux by Stephen Grider](https://www.udemy.com/react-redux)

My github repo where I have cloned the author's starter kit and then applying my changes to and committing and pushing them @
[GettingStartedWithRedux](https://github.com/miniGweek/GettingStartedWithRedux)

The problem is in my reducer ( it is just a simple function now... ) I have hard-coded an array of 6 books with title and id.

```
export default function(){
return [{title : 'Harry Potter', id : 1},
        {title : 'Lord of the Rings', id : 2},
        {title : 'Brotherhood', id : 3},
        {title : 'Magestic', id : 4},
        {title : 'John Carter of Mars', id : 5},
        {title : 'Transman of Gor', id : 6}];
```

}

The **index.js** which is mapping this reducer to the **rootReducer** as follows :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import BooksReducer from './reducer-books';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books : BooksReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

The **container** which uses these reducer are :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { selectBook } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class BookList extends Component {

    renderList(){
        return this.props.books.map( book => {
            return (
                <li key='{book.id}' className='list-group-item'>{book.title}</li>
        );
    });
}
    render(){
        return (
            <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        );
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        books : state.books
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

As you can see, in the list li I am iterating over the list of books and I have mentioned a key which is unique. I still get the following error on my chrome :

[image: The Error]

I can't figure out why the key property is getting 1 appended before it ?

Any advice ?

Comment: Remove the quotes and make it: `key={book.id}`

Comment: You are right it works! Silly me!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

My call is unwanted quotes :

```
 <li key='{book.id}'
```

should be

```
<li key={book.id}
```